# How to upload files to server from html form using python cgi

Tags: python, html, cgi, bioinformatics

I'm a bioinformatics student and I have a problem to upload a file from an html script. I tried using different templates I found on the internet, and I couldn't fix my problem searching other topics on this website.

This is a fragment of my html form script to upload the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<BR>
<CENTER><FORM ACTION="blast_parser.cgi" METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">

<FONT SIZE=+1>Upload your sequence(s) file</FONT>

<BR><INPUT TYPE="file"  NAME= "file" ID="file">
<BR>
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="BLAST!" NAME="submit" ID="submit">
<input type="reset" value="Clear Form"><br>
<BR>
<BR>
```

And this is part of the **blast_parser.cgi** I'm using to upload the file to the server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import glob, subprocess, shlex, sys, re

try: # Windows needs stdio set for binary mode.
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY) # stdin  = 0
    msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY) # stdout = 1
except ImportError:
    pass

def fbuffer(f, chunk_size=10000):
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk: break
        yield chunk

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileitem = form['file']

if fileitem.filename:
    fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
    f = open('/opt/lampp/htdocs/server_v1/uploads/' + fn, 'wb', 10000)
    for chunk in fbuffer(fileitem.file):
        f.write(chunk)
    f.close()
    message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
else:
    message = 'No file was uploaded'

print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html><body>
<p>%s</p>
</body></html>
    """ % (message,)
```

So the output is: 'No file was uploaded'. The problem is that **the test *if fileitem.filename:* renders None** always because ***fileitem* is MiniFieldStorage('file', 'Acinetobacter_pittii_protein.faa')** when I upload a file called Acinetobacter_pittii_protein.faa

I'm using **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and **XAMPP 7.1.10** for Linux.

I just want to upload the file to a server so I can process it. I don't know if you need the rest of the code, I didn't put it all because they are quite long.

I would really appreciate any help with this! :)

Comment: Your code works on Ubuntu in apache2.

As you can see, our two solutions are both kind of equal.

Because of this, plus the fact that the reference says ` When a form is submitted in the ``old'' format (as the query string or as a single data part of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded), the items will actually be instances of the class MiniFieldStorage. In this case, the list, file, and filename attributes are always None. ` [ref](https://docs.python.org/2.0/lib/Using_the_cgi_module.html) : could you check you are sending _multipart/form-data_ (check HTML source in browser)

Comment: **Reminder**: your HTML form syntax is awful. Please learn from the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed is quite easy in Python as well.

For a fully contained example, see my example script below (python3). The code is documented by comments. If you need further clarification, please ask :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Import Basic OS functions
import os
# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb, jinja2
import urllib.request

# enable debugging
cgitb.enable()
# print content type
print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")


# HTML INPUT FORM
HTML = """
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Upload File</h1>
  <form action="sendEx1.py" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File: <input name="file" type="file">
    <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>

{% if filedata %}

<blockquote>

{{filedata}}

</blockquote>

{% endif %}  

</body>
</html>
"""


inFileData = None

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

UPLOAD_DIR='uploads'

# IF A FILE WAS UPLOADED (name=file) we can find it here.
if "file" in form:
    form_file = form['file']
    # form_file is now a file object in python
    if form_file.filename:

        uploaded_file_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIR, os.path.basename(form_file.filename))
        with open(uploaded_file_path, 'wb') as fout:
            # read the file in chunks as long as there is data
            while True:
                chunk = form_file.file.read(100000)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                # write the file content on a file on the hdd
                fout.write(chunk)

        # load the written file to display it
        with open(uploaded_file_path, 'r') as fin:
            inFileData = ""
            for line in fin:
                inFileData += line


headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}

print(jinja2.Environment().from_string(HTML).render(filedata=inFileData))
```

Comment: I tried to run your script and it gives me an error: "Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
End of script output before headers: index_2.cgi

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.28 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.10 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 " Thank in advance for your help!

Comment: what happens when you run it from command line?

Since you see this error, you haven't encountered cgitb.enable() yet. My guess is, some dependency is not installed. Is jinja2 installed?

Also you could check your error log to see what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, I installed jinja2. When I run it in the command line the output is: `Content-type:text/html



<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Upload File</h1>
  <form action="sendEx1.py" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File: <input name="file" type="file">
    <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>

  

</body>
</html> `  Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Okay it finally worked, the error was that I didn't change the chmod for the new file! Thanks you so much!! You saved my life!!